# Remove \n, Cast string to float is not supported

Tags: python, arrays, string, tensorflow

Code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1l2enVyu6rClQllfJZT2w3x8jiAbu-rbd?usp=sharing

I alwas get the error: Cast string to float is not supported

I suppose it‘s because the y-data is like this: '-459\n' ',-125\n' ',198\n' ... ',89\n' ',333\n' ',336'

So the \n is problably causing  the problem, but I don‘t know how to remove it. I tried with notepad++ and the strip method, but it doesn‘t worked.

Is this actually causing the error? How can I resolve it otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like this is because of `y_train`. Try converting `y_train` to an array of floats using below code.

```
# Added this block to remove commas from a single block of string.
y_train = "".join(y_train.tolist())
y_train = y_train.split(",")

# Unchanged code
y_train = [float(v.rstrip()) for v in y_train]
y_train = np.array(y_train, dtype=np.float32)
```

I suggest that that you do this separately and save your `.npz` file again, so you don't have to do any changes in the code of the linked Colab notebook.

Comment: This doesn’t work: Couldn’t convert string to float: -125, I don’t know why the error didn’t pop up at the first argumen -459\n, since there is a “-“too…

Comment: Looking at your data, it is not the '-' character that is causing the problem. I think it is happening only where the first character is ','.

float("-459") will not give any error, float(",-125") will. Editing my answer for this particular case.

But can you tell me first what is the output of len(y_train) and y_train.shape after you call get_data() in your notebook? I think your array contains a single string due to comma misplacing.

Comment: The length is 1000273, the shape (1000273,1), so this is not the problem. So the comma is the problem, not the minus. I didn’t  saw the comma at first! I will try to remove the commas, thanks!

Comment: It worked with the rstrip code when I removed the commas, thank you!